# Powershell: Does calling .NET a function always require parenthesis?

Tags: .net, function, powershell, call, braces

I know that PowerShell function calls don't need specific parentheses like C#, but when I try to call .NET class functions, it seems parentheses are always needed, like:

```
[Int32]::Parse("12")
```

So is this a syntax rule?

Comment: When you say "braces", are you referring to the square brackets (`[]`) around the type name, or the parentheses (`()`) around the arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a rule. More specifically, when you call a method on an object (as opposed to a cmdlet or standalone function), you always use what you are calling braces `()` and you separate your arguments with commas `,`:

```psh
# A cmdlet: no use of (), parameter names and values separated by spaces
$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -ArgumentList @{Name='hello'}

# A method: () are used even with no arguments
$obj.GetType()
```

Note that in English these are *much* more commonly referred to as *parentheses*, and braces typically refer to *curly braces* which are these: `{}`.

Comment: parenthesis, parentheses, very nice English hit.

Comment: IIRC, since PowerShell v3 your can omit parentheses if you passing single script block literal. For example `[Int32]::Parse{12}` is the same as `[Int32]::Parse({12})`.

Comment: @PetSerAl nice, I've seen that for the `.ForEach` and `.Where` methods that were added and thought it was specific to those. I guess it makes more sense that they would do it for all methods, even if they had those 2 in mind at the time. I think it's important to note though that in the case of something like `[int]::Parse{12}` the scriptblock is _not_ being executed. It's being cast to the argument type, in this case string, so it works with `{12}`, it won't work with `{12*2}` for example.

Answer (score 4):

The way you refer to a .NET type in general is to put the typename in square brackets e.g. `'' -is [string]`.  Although `'' -is 'string'` works as well, I find it easier to tell that a .NET type is being referred to when square brackets are used.

The way you refer to static type members is to use `::` on the type specifier as in `[System.Int32]::Parse("12")`.  Note that PowerShell will prepend `System.` your typename, if it can't find it as you've specified.  This makes for a nice shortcut.  There are also type accelerators that appear the same way e.g. `[int]::Parse("12")`.